# transfer users and previlegs to a new server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have an existing old Windows Server with mySQL and the MySQL Workbench.
Now I want to transfer all schemas and Users with their previlegs to a new installed server.

Databases (Schemas) were transferred with no problem (Data Export).
But I can't transfer the users!

How can I backup and restore all Users and their privileges to the new server?

Thanks for help!
Best regards, 
Ronny

added screenshot1:
[image: missing mysql database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the mysql database same as the previous one on your old server / machine.
For this you can take the backup of mysql folder in data directory and copy to new server..
If that shows error while restart then use mysql_upgrade.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for reply.
in previous versions of MySQL Workbench, I could export the "mysql" Database.
But in the last version I dont see the "mysql" database in the export dialog anymore.
so i can't export this one :(

Comment: ok I solved the last problem with a manual export/import on the commandline:
mysqldump -u root -p mysql > mysql_Datenbank.sql

      Commandbox:
      cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin
      mysql -u root -p mysql < mysql_Datenbank.sql